# check timeout listener

Tags: java, android, timeout, listener

I'm trying to create a screen saver for my app i want to show it when user doesn't touch or do anything for 1 min.
Is there any listener for this ? how do i check it ? it could show up at any activity.

Comment: What have you got so far? Start with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

In extremis you should use a countdown listener with OnFinish time set to 1 minute and restart in each user’s click

Comment: Try to explain your answer with some code snippet for better practice . Thx